# How to implement an add() to sorted list based on multiple comparators; parametrized comparator?

Tags: java, insert, comparator

I need to implement the following function. I'm open to using the best class, but I'm not sure whether I should use SortedSet or TreeSet (as in Set myEmailsAscending = new TreeSet(new DateAscendingComparator()); // emails are always in ascending order).

```
public void addEmail(Email email)//The prototype isn't to be altered.
{
Comparator comp;
if(getCurrentSortingMethod()=="DateDescending") comp=DateDescendingComparator;
else if(getCurrentSortingMethod()=="DateAscending") comp=DateAscendingComparator;
...//other comparators

int index = Collections.binarySearch(getEmails(), email, new comp());// Search where to insert according to the current sorting method.
getEmails().add(-index-1, email);}// Add the item to the list
}
```

Is that the proper syntax to choose comparator?
I'd like to avoid creating multiple Comparator classes so is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why not just use a TreeSet, which will do everything for you?

Comment: Set<Email> myEmailsAscending = new TreeSet<Email>(new DateAscendingComparator()); // emails are always in ascending order

Comment: But how would I change order of a set of emails later? How would that affect this function, add()?

Comment: You could dump the contents of one set into the other when the user switches. Or keep both around, insert into both, and remember which one represents the "current" sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues:

You should use `equals()` for string comparison and not `==`.

The usage of `new` is wrong. I'd suggest the following:

```
Comparator comp;
if (getCurrentSortingMethod().equals("DateDescending")) {
   comp = new DateDescendingComparator();
} else if (getCurrentSortingMethod().equals("DateAscending")) {
   comp = new DateAscendingComparator();
} ...

int index = Collections.binarySearch(getEmails(), email, comp);
```

Note how the `new` has been moved inside the `if` blocks.

As an alternative to all this, you could use a [`SortedSet<Email>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) with the appropriate comparator. The set will be automatically kept sorted in the correct order.

Comment: I'm open to using the best class, but I'm not sure whether I should use SortedSet or TreeSet (as above in Set<Email> myEmailsAscending = new TreeSet).

Comment: `TreeSet` is-a `SortedSet`. The latter is an interface and the former is a concrete implementation.

Comment: But how would I change order of a set of emails later? How would that affect this function, add()?

Answer (score 0):

Accept a Comparator in your class constructor and/or provide a setter for it.
Then just use the Comparator inside your `addEmail(Email email)`. If no comparator has been set then use natural ordering.

Have a look at [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) and how it deals with comparators and natural ordering. Try to adapt it for your own list implementation.

Comment: The prototype isn't to be altered.